# How can I automate MariaDB installation with a shell script?

Tags: mysql, shell, mariadb, centos7

I'm writing a script to install various things automatically in CentOS 7 but I can't figure out how I can automate the input during the mysql_secure_installation.
The current MariaDB part of my script is below:

```
#MySQL (MariaDB)
function mysql (){
echo ~~Now Installing MySQL -Attended Installation~~
sleep 1
yum -y install mariadb-server mariadb
systemctl start mariadb
mysql_secure_installation
systemctl enable mariadb.service
echo ~~MySQL Installation Complete~~
sleep 2
exit 0
} #MySQL End
```

Comment: What about this isn't working?

Comment: I need it to be an unattended installation, besides that it works perfectly.

Comment: What part of that requires interaction? What interaction does it require?

Comment: `Enter current password for root (enter for none):`
`Set root password? [Y/n]`
`New password:`
`Re-enter new password:`
`Remove anonymous users? [Y/n]`
`Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n]`
`Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n]`
`Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n]`

Comment: During which component? Presumably `mysql_secure_installation`? I'm assuming that's a script and you can probably just find out what it is doing and do the same things yourself. If not you can always try feeding the input it wants to the script/etc. via standard input.

Comment: A few good answers here on github: https://gist.github.com/Mins/4602864

Comment: In addition to what @Quickredfox said , please have a look at  http://bertvv.github.io/notes-to-self/2015/11/16/automating-mysql_secure_installation/